# Why does <b> tag work here and not the <strong> tag?

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why the `<b>` tag works here and the `<strong>` does not.

Thanks.

html

```
<ul id="one">
  <li>one</li> 
  <li>two</li>
</ul>

<ul id="two">
  <li>three</li> 
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$( '#one li' ).each(function( index ) {
$( this ).prepend( "<b>" + index + ": </b>" );
});

$( '#two li' ).each(function( index ) {
$( this ).prepend( "<strong>" + index + ": </strong>" );
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cXArG/

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/cXArG/2/

Comment: Uncheck 'Normalized CSS' :)

Comment: Cool, you seem to have 5 of the same answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work, it's just that the Normalize CSS that you're including is setting the strong tags font-weight to normal, so it doesn't appear bold. In the Filter Options, you can uncheck Normalize CSS to remove it.

You could add a color to see the strong tags for example:

```
strong { color:red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GefgV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The `<b>` tag is for influencing the markup (bold font), whereby the `<strong>` tag is to describe a logical/semantical aspect of the text ("[It defines important text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp)"). How this semantics is formatted is not the business of this tag.

Comment: Standard font-weight of `strong` will be bold. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/strong.html

Comment: @Pieter not for me :-) (Mac Os 10.8.4, Chrome 28.0.)

Comment: @Pieter that's true, but it is not what is supposed to do `strong` tag, setting style to bold, it is not consistent across browsers

Comment: No, I know it's based on semantics. The conclusion is that browser don't follow HTML defaults? (provided by W3C)

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to  or **, this is an css scenario**

on JSFiddle  is shown like regular text using stylesheet

if you inspect the element you will find this css rules applied to

```
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

which makes it like regular text

Answer (score 0):

```
/*http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css (line: 17)*/
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<strong>` tag works just fine, it is prepended in the code but jsFiddle's CSS styling removes bold weight from the `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In Fiddle Options, uncheck 'normalized CSS'. `<strong>` should be displayed with `font-weight: bold` as standard (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/strong.html)